# is there a way to calculate the greater and smaller of player scoreboard values in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to make a map, there is a scoreboard objective called anger that when a player’s anger is greater than 300, player will sometime floats. when the player’s anger is greater than 1000, he randomly explodes, but I do not know how to use command blocks to calculate if the player's anger is greater or smaller, anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to test for scores you can do with this command:

```
execute as @a[scores={Anger=300..1000}] if entity @s run effect give @s levitation 1 0
```

This will give all players with the `Anger` score a levitation effect for 1 second with the amplifier of 1, the `0` at the end is the amplifier, i.e. `0` will give you an amplifier of 1, `1` will give you an amplifier of 2, etc.

You can also add `true` at the end to hide the effect particles:

```
effect give @s levitation 1 0 true
```

The first command will test for when a player has an `Anger` score from 300 to 1000. I don't really know how to make a randomizer but if you use another `scoreboard` you can add the levitation effect every 20 seconds or whatever delay you'd like.

```
/scoreboard objectives add Random dummy
```

Then you can put this in a repeating command block:

```
scoreboard players add @a Random 1
```

This will add 1 point every 20:th of a second to the score, so 20 points a second. Using this you can test for how many seconds you'd like the delay to be by just testing for a score 20 times bigger, lets say we want a 20-second delay:

```
execute as @a[scores={Random=400..400,Anger=300..1000}] if entity @s run 
effect give @s levitation 1 0
```

After this you put a chain command block with a command that resets the `Random` score:

```
execute as @a[scores={Random=400..400,Anger=300..1000}] if entity @s run 
scoreboard players set @s Random 0
```

You can do the same with the above 1000 scenario, and you can add another dummy score if you'd like the delay to be different from your first.

About the `score` testing:

When you test for a score you do that within the target selector, `@a[scores={"here"}]`. You specify the score's name first, `@a[scores={Anger=}`, then you add the score you'd like to test for using 2 dots `..`. In front of the dots is the minimum score, and after is the maximum score, If I'd like to test for a score from 0 to 347 I'd write:

```
execute as @a[scores={Anger=..347}] if entity @s run *command*
```

And if I'd like to test for a score of 1000 or more I'd write:

```
execute as @a[scores={Anger=1000..}] if entity @s run *command*
```

Make sure to add the `if entity @s` after the selector `@a[]`. This makes sure the command only runs when the players' scores actually are correct, so the player doesn't get stuck in a loop.

Comment: For the rng, you can use the rng predicate (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Predicate, https://misode.github.io/predicate/). Using pseudo-rng is this case would be bad as the command is ran all the time. In case the OP isn't using datapacks, I can't think of other soulutions.